# Sending JavaScript image to PHP with post

Tags: javascript, php, image, post, upload

I have the following section of JavaScript that I am  working with:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "/upload.php";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);
xhr.send(file);
```

`upload.php` does a dumpvar of `$_File` and `$_POST`. It also echos a logfile. The presence of the logfile indicates that the PHP program runs as planned, but no posts or files are received.

How can I receive the file sent by the script above?

Comment: try to read from [raw input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input)

Comment: I added: $xml = file_get_contents('php://memory'); echo $xml. No output resulted.

Comment: I removed the var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); to eliminate an xmr already defined error.

Comment: I changed to $xml = file_get_contents('php://input'); and got what looks like an image.

Comment: Still having trouble parsing the raw data.